# SQL Server round after division

Tags: sql-server, division, rounding

In a stored procedure I have an expression like

```
select @some_val_in_percents = (@total_val / 100) * @some_val
```

If I use the `Round` function like this:

```
select @some_val_in_percents = Round((@total_val / 100) * @some_val, 0)
```

will the result be rounded when the whole expression is calculated or will `(@total_val / 100)` be rounded and than multiplied by `@some_val`?

Comment: maybe someone will tell me a better way than round )))))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be calculating the percent value wrongly. Here's what I would expect it to be like:

```
@some_val * 100 / @total_val
```

As for the `ROUND()` function, it will act on the final result of the expression, not on the partial result. So, first the expression is evaluated completely, then `ROUND()` is applied to the result.

Note also (in case you haven't already known it) that if both operands of the division operator are integers, SQL Server will perform an integer division, i.e. the result of the division would be *rounded down* to the nearest integer even *before* `ROUND()` is applied. If you want to avoid that, make sure that at least one of the operands is not integer, e.g. like this:

```
ROUND(@some_val * 100.0 / @total_val, 2)
```

Note also the second argument (precision), which is required in [Transact-SQL `ROUND()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`Round` will be calculated after its contents is evaluated.

Therefore `(@total_val / 100) * @some_val` will be rounded.